# Windows 7 can VPN to Windows Server 2012, Windows 10 cannot

Tags: windows-10, vpn, windows-server-2012

I recently upgraded a couple of systems to Windows 10. The new systems cannot VPN to my Windows 2012 server at home. But my old Windows 7 workstations can VPN with no problem.

[image]

The Windows 10 systems can VPN to the work server with no problem (no idea what version of Windows server that is). Just having trouble hitting my home server

Everything is pretty vanilla.

Is there something special I need to do either on the server or clients to VPN?

thanks - dave

Comment: What error do you receive ? Did check if the ports you use to connect to the VPN on your W10 machine are not blocked ?

Comment: @Overmind - I added a screenshot of the error. I'm sure the ports are open because I can VPN to the server from Windows 7 clients. And I can VPN to our work server from the clients.

Answer (score 0):

After you screenshot, it became clear.
There is a problem of VPN protocol compatibility between W10 and W7.

Check the protocol type on your VPN server and then select the proper one from W10.

Probably the server is configured with PPTP and you try to connect using L2TP.

On the windows 10 system, when you setup your VPN connection, select your type of VPN connection (low-most option). Select Point Tunneling Protocol (PPTP) if that is what you have configured on your server and it should instantly connect.